# LINQ : filter multiple string values - partial match - not full match as in multiple online examples

Tags: arrays, string, linq, filter

There are many good examples of searching multiple string values in LINQ [e.g.](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-linq-to-perform-quot-where-in-value1-value2-quot-queries)

```
public static Product[] GetProducts(Guid[] prodIDs)
{
   return (from p in GetProducts()
           where prodIDs.Contains(p.ProductID)
           select p).ToArray<Product>();
}
```

I have a list of Products that I need to match from a customer,
but I dont have an exact match - the Customers List Of Products contains my ProductID - but it is not exact - e.g.

```
Customer             MyCompany
Description          Description
Prod1XY              Prod1
AProd2B              Prod2
XXXProd3             Prod3
```

I thus cannot filter from the prodIDs [string array] because `Prod1` does not contain `Prod1XY`
and thus cannot use the examples that are available.

How can I effectively change (reverse) the working examples 
as to search CustomerProducts where it contains my Product Description please?

So to confirm : this is not a duplicate. The examples use the `string[] x`
input parameter and then searches:
where `x.contains`

I need help to get it : `myProducts.Contains(x)`

another online example modified to show the situation:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

   var table = new[] {
      new { uid = 1 },
      new { uid = 2 },
      new { uid = 3 },
      new { uid = 4 },
      new { uid = 5 }
   };

   var stringarray = new[] { "1", "5", "10" };

   var results = from xx in table
                 where table.Contains(stringarray)
                 select xx;

   foreach (var result in results) {
      Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.uid.ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear enough what you are trying to accomplish, but under assumption that you want to select all products where ProductID contains any value from specified list, it looks like that it:

```
public static Product[] GetProducts(string[] prodIDs)
{
   return (from p in GetProducts()
           where prodIDs.Any(id=>p.ProductID.Contains(id))
           select p).ToArray<Product>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static Product[] GetProducts(string[] prodIDs)
{
   return (
        from p in GetProducts()
        from q in prodIDs
        where p.ProductID.IndexOf(q) > -1
        select p)
        .ToArray<Product>();
}
```